# oracle rownum invalid identifier

Tags: database, oracle, rownum

I'm trying to get the top 3 max salary of each department however at the end of my code at q.salary i receive the following error: ORA-00904: "Q"."SALARY": invalid identifier

here is my code

```
with query as (
   select max(salary), department_id 
   from employees 
   group by department_id
)
SELECT ROWNUM as RANK, 
       e.last_name, 
       e.salary
FROM (
   select department_id, salary
   from employees e, 
        query q 
   where e.salary = q.salary
)
where rownums <=3
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the column expression max(salary) ...

```
select max(salary) max_salary ...
```

... and then refer to it as max_salary subsequently.

Also "rownums" should be "rownum".

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the aggregate a name:

```
select max(salary) as salary, 
       department_id 
from employees group by department_id
```